# PHP - MongoClient connections stacking up, not closing

Tags: php, mongodb, connection-pooling

I've got a class that is pulling and aggregating data from a Mongo DB. This is all working fine...I have multiple queries being run for a connection under the same connection (in the same class). However, every time I refresh the page, a new connection is opened...I can see this in my mongod output:

```
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:46770 #12 (6 connections now open)
```

I see this count up and up with every page refresh. This should be fine, I think; however, the connections **never seem to close**.

After a while, the connections / locks take up too much memory in Mongo, and I can no longer run the queries.

This dev environment is on a 32-bit version of Mongo, so I don't know if this is only happening because of that. (Our prod env is 64-bit, and I cannot change the dev env right now.)

My question is: **Should I be closing the connection after all the queries have been made for a particular user?** How should I be handling the connection pool?

The service class:

```
class MongoService{
    protected $mongoServer;
    public function setSpokenlayerMongoServer($mongoServer)
    { $this->mongoServer = $mongoServer; }

    protected $mongoUser;
    public function setSpokenlayerMongoUser($mongoUser)
    { $this->mongoUser = $mongoUser; }

    protected $mongoPassword;
    public function setSpokenlayerMongoPassword($mongoPassword)
    { $this->mongoPassword = $mongoPassword; }

    protected $conn;
    public function setServiceConnection($conn)
    { $this->conn = $conn; }

    public function connect(){
        try {
            $this->conn = $this->getMongoClient();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            /* Can't connect to MongoDB! */
            // logException($e);
            die("Can't do anything :(");
        }
    }

    public function getDatabase($name){
        if(!isset($this->conn)){
            $this->connect();
        }
        return $this->conn->$name;
    }

    protected function getMongoClient($retry = 3) {
        $connectString= "mongodb://".$this->mongoUser.":".$this->mongoPassword."@". $this->mongoServer."";
        try {
            return new MongoClient($connectString);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            /* Log the exception so we can look into why mongod failed later */
            // logException($e);
        }
        if ($retry > 0) {
            return $this->getMongoClient(--$retry);
        }
        throw new Exception("I've tried several times getting MongoClient.. Is mongod really running?");
    }
}
```

And in the service class where the queries are:

```
protected function collection(){
    if(!isset($this->collection)){
        $this->collection =  $this->db()->selectCollection($this->collectionName);
    }
    return $this->collection;
}
```

And then a query is done like so:

```
$results = $this->collection()->aggregate($ops);
```

Is this correct behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue if you're using Azure IaaS, possible issue on other platforms.

One option would be to change the Mongo configuration:

```
MongoDefaults.MaxConnectionIdleTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

This would kill all idle connections after 5 minutes.